# ArcGIS Pro Python Field Calculating

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-parser, if-else

I am trying to use Python in ArcGIS Pro to cleanse some data via imported Excel sheets. The expression works, but the Code Block if-else statement to return nothing if !Street_Id! is  returns an error.

Address

```
str(!Street_ID!) + ' ' + !Street!.split("/")[0]
```

Code Block

```
def f(x): ' '
if !Street_ID! = 'Null'
return x
else return str(!Street_ID!) + ' ' + !Street!.split("/")[0]
```

Error

```
File"<string>",line 2
if!Street_ID! = 'Null'
   ^
SynatxError: invalid syntax
```

[image: Results using the expression in Python IDLE]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a bunch of things wrong with your code:

- Incorrect code invocation
- Incorrect function definition (placing a non-comment to the right of the colon)
- Poor function naming (far better to keep everything you use, so you don't have to debug every time you use it, but that requires descriptive naming)
- Failure to pass in the values to be used in the expression string
- No indentation (required part of the Python language)
- Failure to place a space between the `if` keyword and logical expression
- Using assignment (`=`) instead of equivalence (`==`) for a logical test
- Using expression field delimiters in Python code
- Assuming a NULL value will match the string 'Null' (instead it maps to `None`)
- Improper use of early exit (after a `return` you don't need an `else`)
- Performing string math (using `format` is best practice)

When the smoke clears, the corrected result looks like this:

---

Expression:
`usefulName(!Street!,!StreetID!,'nullValue')`

---

Expression type:
`Python`

---

Code block:

```
def usefulName(street_val,street_id,x):
    if (street_id == None):
        return x
    return "{:s} {:s}".format(street_id,street_val.split("/")[0])
```

---

If you want to avoid early exit (some organizations/programs forbid it as confusing), then the code block would look like:

```
def usefulName(street_val,street_id,x):
    result = x
    if (street_id != None):
        result = "{:s} {:s}".format(street_id,street_val.split("/")[0])
    return result
```

And the ternary logic form would look like:

```
def usefulName(street_val,street_id,x):
    return "{:s} {:s}".format(street_id,street_val.split("/")[0]) if street_id else x
```

Which actually compresses down to a simple Python expression of:

```
"{:s} {:s}".format(!StreetID!,!Street!.split("/")[0]) if !StreetID! else 'nullValue'
```

though that's probably a bit obscure for reuse.

Answer (score 0):

You need a double equal sign, a colon at the ends, and proper indentation for sure.

Consider writing your code in a Python IDE that shows syntax errors during code development.

```
 def f(x):
    if !Street_ID! == 'Null':
        return x
    else:
        return str(!Street_ID!) + ' ' + !Street!.split("/")[0]
```

Comment: `!Street!` and `!Street_ID!` should be passed into function `f` as parameters (`f(!Street!,!StreetID!,'defVal')`, and function `f` should be defined with three parameters `def f(street_val,street_id,x)` and therefore won't have the bang sandwich inside the function (`return str(street_id) + ' ' + street_val.split("/")[0]`)

Comment: Thanks for catching that.

Comment: I am going to research to comprehend the way Vince explained passing into functions as parameters and defining the f function with parameters and will post my answer after the fact, I get what he is saying generally when using parameters, but at the same time I need to comprehend how to script it out and why it needs to be expressed in the code block concerning indentation. I did catch onto the bang sandwich at least.