# Field Calculating using Python Parser with Standard SQL Query Layers & Views in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, arcgis-pro, sql, python-parser

I have been given the task to extract PASER scores from a comprehensive table of of PASER_byYear. I would like to take the time to create a view and query layers using SQL, but do to time constraints, I simply used the the SQL clause GUI in ArcGIS Pro to output this:

```
last_edited_date >= timestamp '2020-01-01 00:00:00' And last_edited_date < timestamp '2020-12-29 
00:00:00' OR last_edited_date >= timestamp '2016-01-01' AND last_edited_date < timestamp '2016-12-29'
```

The goal from here is to use Python subtract 2016 PASER scores from 2020 PASER scores for for identical road segments (Road_Segment_ID) and if the out put is -n multiply by -1 and if the output is +n multiply by -1.

Thus a simple analysis of road condition over time can be related an overlayed feature for scheduled paving in 2020.

I posted a question last week as [ArcGIS Pro Python Field Calculating](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365323/arcgis-pro-python-field-calculating), and the admins and commenters helped immensely. Although I have been able to pick up on some things, I have a lot of learning about the languages/syntax necessary to make my job easier / be a better GIS professional.

The tricky thing with the current task is calling out only the year, then writing an expression that subtracts integers from the PASER_Score field based on the Last_Edited_Date field.

Expression:

```
PASER_2016(PASER_Score, last_edited_date)
```

Code Block:

```
def PASER_2016(PASER_Score, last_edited_date, x):
result = x
if !last_edited_date!.rsplit("/")[0] == '2016':
    result = !PASER_SCORE!
    return result
```

[image]

[image]

```
PASER_2016(PASER_Score, last_edited_date) 

def PASER_2016(PASER_Score, last_edited_date):
result = PASER_Score
if last_edited_date.year == 2016:
    return result
```

The expression checks out, but I am prompted an error message of "NameError": name 'PASER_Score' is not defined.

[image]

Expression:

```
PASER_2016(!PASER_Score!, !last_edited_date!)
```

Code Block:

```
def PASER_2016(PASER_Score, last_edited_date):
result = PASER_Score
if last_edited_date.year == 2016:
    return result
```

[image]

Comment: Date datatype. the whole timestamp functionality in SQL and Python has kind of thrown me off, have been scouring 3W schools to read up on how to navigate them in a simple fashion.

Comment: Expression checks out, but returns are Null. I am guessing that has to do with how I am defining the result?

Comment: I left out the `.year` for `if last_edited_date.year == 2016`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PASER_2016(!PASER_Score!, !last_edited_date!)

def PASER_2016(PASER_Score, last_edited_date):
result = PASER_Score
if last_edited_date.year == 2016:
    return result
```

[image]

To replace Null values

```
replaceNull(!PASER_2016!)

def replaceNull(x):
    if x is None:
       return 0
    else:
       return x
```